# How to listen for dispatched events from container children?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm using an accordion container that has it's creation policy set to auto. One of the accordion's children is a spark border container that has a data grid within it. Currently, I'm using the data grid's **creationComplete property** to call a function; similarly, I'm using the **dragComplete property** to call another function.

How can I add listeners for events (creationComplete & dragComplete) via **actionscript**? The obvious problem is that the accordion does not create all its children on creation (nor do I want it to), so I can't simply use something like: `datagrid.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: Is the Accordion declared using mxml or actionscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion.addEventListener("childAdd"...)  ?

Then check which child is added, and if the datagrid, then add the appropriate event listeners to it then.